# Carrierwave + Rails 5: read directory vs store directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

Carrierwave's [enter link description here](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#changing-the-storage-directory) gives both the directory where Carrierwave uploads files and the directory where Carrierwave looks for files. However, I'd like to know if there's a way to define something like a `read_dir`, which would be the path where Carrierwave looked for files, and leave the `store_dir` only for storing files.

I know this probably doesn't make much practical sense, but I'd just like to know.

Answer (score 3):

You can calculate `store_dir` based on some condition of the object. You can also set this condition when you need a different directory. For example:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :use_directory_for_storing

  mount_uploader :file, MyFileUploader
end

class MyFileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  # ...
  def store_dir
    if model.use_directory_for_storing
      "some/directory/for/storing"
    else
      "some/directory/for/reading"
    end
  end
end

# Usage

object = MyModel.new(params)
object.use_directory_for_storing = true

object.save # the file will be stored in ".../some/directory/for/storing/" directory

object = MyModel.last
# will look for the file in the ".../some/directory/for/reading/" directory
object.file.path # => ".../some/directory/for/reading/..."
```